# How to generate setters only from a declared variable in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javabeans

The problem here is that I am writing really big huge mappers.
A mapper maps(copies) data from BeanA to BeanB.

To copy the fields from BeanA to BeanB I do it like this in a method in the mapper:

```
    public static BeanB mapToBeanB(BeanA input){
            BeanB output = new BeanB();
            output.setName(input.getName());
            output.setvariable1(input.getInfo());
            output.set***** (and so on)
            .......
            return output;
    }
```

I have to copy between 45 and 130 fields(bean properties) from each Bean and I have 27 Beans to copy. So you can image how much effort this costs.

My question: Is there a way of letting eclipse generate all those setters for me? 

Attention here, I don't mean the usual getters and setters generated with:

[Right mouse click inside the editor -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters]
because this only works inside the bean itself. I want to be able to generate those setters only outside the bean.

I hope the question is clear.

```
public class BeanB {
    private String name;
    private String nickname;
    private String variable1;
    private String variable2;
    private String variable3;

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
    return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getVariable1() {
        return variable1;
    }

    public void setVariable1(String variable1) {
        this.variable1 = variable1;
    }

    public String getVariable2() {
        return variable2;
    }

    public void setVariable2(String variable2) {
        this.variable2 = variable2;
    }

    public String getVariable3() {
        return variable3;
    }

    public void setVariable3(String variable3) {
        this.variable3 = variable3;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate getters/settes in the code :

Right mouse click inside the editor -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters

If you want to specify the call of multiple setters at once like

```
BeanB result=new BeanB();
result.setNickname("nickname");
result.setVariable1();
result.setVariable1();
```

and so on, I think there is no such functionality inside eclipse.

But why don't you put all the class variables into a constructor and then create a new object in the mapper using this constructor? This way you don't need to specify any setters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand my question wasn't clear enough, can you try again? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Don says, Eclipse has a wizard for generating getters and setters.  What he didn't mention is that the wizard has a button to select all setters for generation.

(I found a link to the Eclipse Help info on this, only to discover that it doesn't describe that button.  Duh!)